# KOMA letter with logo towards top of page

Tags: scrlttr2, logos

I would like to write a KOMA letter with a logo towards the top right corner of the first page.  (See the attached image.) [image]

I'm using LuaLaTeX in TeXLive on Win10.

So far, my efforts to `setkomavar{firsthead}` and `setkomavar{fromlogo}` do not produce an image.

Using `documentclass{scrartcl}` and `scrletter`, I was able to set the logo using firsthead, but my attempts to move it up failed.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[
 a4paper,
 11pt,
 backaddress=off,
 pagenumber=no,
 fromalign=locationright,
 enlargefirstpage=false,
 foldmarks=off]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

%\makeatletter
%  \@setplength{firstheadvpos}{-20mm} % doesn't seem to move logo up
%  \@addtoplength[-]{firstheadvpos}{40mm} % also seems to do nothing
%\makeatother

\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Santa Claus\\ North Pole H0H 0H0\\ Canada}
% \setkomavar{firsthead}{\hfill\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Colin Rowat \\ South Pole}
\opening{Dear Colin,}
\lipsum
\closing{Ho Ho Ho,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you need `fromlogo=on,` to see the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `fromlogo=true` to the options and then

```latex
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\smash{\raisebox{1cm}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}}}
```

to move the logo up:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[
 a4paper,
 11pt,
 backaddress=off,
 pagenumber=no,
 fromalign=locationright,
 fromlogo=true,% <- added
 enlargefirstpage=false,
 foldmarks=off
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Santa Claus\\ North Pole H0H 0H0\\ Canada}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\smash{\raisebox{1cm}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}}}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Colin Rowat \\ South Pole}
\opening{Dear Colin,}
\lipsum
\closing{Ho Ho Ho,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

---

Or you can remove the `fromalign` option and add

```latex
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Santa Claus\\ North Pole H0H 0H0\\ Canada}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
\setkomavar{location}{\raggedleft\usekomavar{fromaddress}}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{\hfill\usekomavar{fromlogo}}
```

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[
 a4paper,
 11pt,
 backaddress=off,
 pagenumber=no,
 %fromalign=locationright,% <- removed
 enlargefirstpage=false,
 foldmarks=off
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Santa Claus\\ North Pole H0H 0H0\\ Canada}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
\setkomavar{location}{\raggedleft\usekomavar{fromaddress}}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{\hfill\usekomavar{fromlogo}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Colin Rowat \\ South Pole}
\opening{Dear Colin,}
\lipsum
\closing{Ho Ho Ho,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful: thank you.  In practice, is there any difference between your two solutions?

Comment: In the first solution the logo is raised up from the location and `\smash` hiddes the height of the raised logo. In the second solution the logo is positioned in page header.